# How come the output of following code : DoSecond

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        switch (printf("Do"))
        {
        case 1:
            printf("First\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Second\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Default\n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain how above code works? How does `switch` jump to `case2` label?

Answer (score 4):

Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for `printf()`. It mentions

> #### Return value
>
> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

Here, the return value of the `printf()` call is used as the `switch` statement controlling expression value. So, in this case, for printing the string `"Do"`, it returns 2. This matches the case label `2`.

Then, the standard output is line buffered. You did not have a *flushing* instruction or a `newline` after the first `printf()`, so the consecutive output from the next `printf()` call is juxtaposed to the output buffer and finally after meeting the `newline`, it gets flushed together to the console / terminal, displaying `"DoSecond"`.

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standard for a hosted environment.

Answer (score 2):

The return value for [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is

> Number of characters written if successful or a negative value if an error occurred.

So `"Do"` has 2 characters, so the switch drops into `case 2:`